# How to create a stringOf<Union type> in typescript which enables the string to only match the combionations of the given strings

Tags: typescript, string, typescript-generics, union-types

The goal is to create a type stringOf which should should be a string with all the combination of the unionType.
How could I create this type?
example:

```
type stringOf<T extends string> = // the code should go here
type resultType = stringOf<"1" | "2" | "3">;
expected resultType = "1" | "2" | "3" | "12" | "21" | "22" || "23" | "31" | "32" | "33"
```

Comment: Type declarations are meant to be simple and straight-forward. You should write validator function to assert whether the value match your business rules.

Comment: Why just combinations of length 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a template literal to generate all possible length two combinations of the passed union by referencing the union twice `${T}${T}`. You also seem to want the type to contain the original union so add `| T`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAzsBOBLAdgcwPIDMA8AVKEAHsBMgCYywIqoB8UAvFAAYAkA3rgL4ffNQAfKLgBQoSFHgQYAVwA2wXOGhM4SNFmwAiAIxbBULQCZ9QrQGYttANxA)

```
type stringOf<T extends string> = `${T}${T}` | T
type resultType = stringOf<"1" | "2" | "3">;
```